# Action App\Http\Controllers\Controller@action not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to submit a form, but I always get `Action App\Http\Controllers\About@show not defined` even though the function `show` is defined:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;


class AboutController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('about.contact');
    }

    public function show()
    {
        return view('about.contactshow');
    }

}
```

This is my blade template `about\contact.blade.php`:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'About@show', 'method' => 'post')) !!}

    {!! Form::label('username','Username',array('id'=>'user','class'=>'')) !!}
    {!! Form::text('username','user 1',array('id'=>'user','class'=>'', 'placeholder' => 'user 1')) !!}

    {!! Form::submit('Click Me!') !!}


{!! Form::close() !!}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your controller is named `AboutController`, but your trying to access `About`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve it.
First I had to change `'action' => 'About@show'` to `'action' => 'AboutController@show'`

Then I had to register all Controller Actions in **routes.php**:

```
Route::post('contact_show', [
    'uses' => 'AboutController@show'
  ]);

Route::get('contact_create', [
    'uses' => 'AboutController@create'
  ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

That's all, because of routes file `web.php` . Plz check out you routes file

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.

The problem was with `routes/web.php`. I was building my app one step at a time, and because of that I passed a second array to my route using `'only'` like this, to make it create the index route **only**:

```
Route::resource('model', 'ModelController', [
     'only' => ['index']
]);
```

But after creating the 'create' view, I couldn't pass data to `store` function in my controller. I found out because the `store` function requires an explicit route (as mentioned above). So I added it to the `'only'` array like this and it worked like a charm:

```
Route::resource('model', 'ModelController', [
    'only' => [
        'index',
        'create',
        'store',
    ]
]);
```

(Laravel v. 7.4.0)

Comment: What's the purpose of only?

Comment: @HashimAziz It's stated in [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes), probably meaning that to use route resource on **only** a handful of routes, the **only** array must be passed to resource

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the good controller!!

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'AboutController@show', 'method' => 'post')) !!}
```

instead of:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'About@show', 'method' => 'post')) !!}
```

It's trying to get the action About@show but you didn't define it like this in your controller!!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Now i get `Action App\Http\Controllers\AboutController@show not defined`.
Only after adding the routes it works.

Comment: Your route should be defined like this in your `web.php` or `routes.php` depending on the version of laravel you're using:

`Route::get('your_route', 'AboutController@show');`

Comment: Interesting because I thought the point of having an `action(...)` method is so we won't have to define a route explicitly. If I still have to define a named route, why will I still need to use this `action` option? Personal preference, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, actually, I think from now its your choice to decide if you use the route or the controller. Personnally, I find it more explicit to call the controller, but that's just from my POV.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but it wasnt my controller name that was wrong (web.php and actual file name were 100% correct). Due to an earlier 'refactor' - it replaced my form action/method.
So my form opener looked like so:

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'AdminBankingDetailController', 'class'=>'m-form m-form--state']) !!}
```

Instead of like so (for the create view/page):

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'AdminBankingDetailController@store', 'class'=>'m-form m-form--state']) !!}
```

Make sure it has an @*action* on your form.

Answer (score -1):

When you get this error, it's possible that you entered the wrong spelling in the web.php or another action method. Simply go and check the spelling.